# Find em banco mongoose pelo Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando acessar o banco mongoose, fazendo um find no nodejs. 
No mongoose, tenho os seguintes dados:

```
Client:{  
  name: {type: String, trim: true, required: false, default: ""},  
  address:{  
    country: {type: String, trim: true, required: false, default: ""},  
    cep : {type: String, trim: true, required: false, default: ""},  
    state: {type: String, trim: true, required: false, default: ""},  
    city: {type: String, trim: true, required: false, default: ""},  
    neighborhood: {type: String, trim: true, required: false, default: ""},  
    street: {type: String, trim: true, required: false, default: ""},  
    number: {type: Number, required: false, default: 0},  
    complement: {type: String, trim: true, required: false, default: ""}  
  },  
}
```

E faço o seguinte find no nodejs:

```
var cepClient = req.body.cep;  
Client.findOne({address:{cep: req.body.cep}} , function(err, cepClient) {...)};
```

Quero verificar se o cep que estou procurando já encontra-se cadastrado, caso não a variável cepClient irá retornar null. 
Porém desta forma acima não consigo acessar a variável cep dentro de address que esta dentro de Client. Como faço para fazer um `Find` de uma variável dentro de um `Array`?

Answer (score 2):

No lugar de `{address:{cep: req.body.cep}}`

Tende desta forma : `{address.cep : req.body.cep}`